# I need to push into an array values based on a specific condition, what is the correct way to do this?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a forcycle that contains a condition (and an incremental value i):

```
if(condition)){$arr[$i] = array("value" => $node->nodeValue));}
else{$arr[$i] = array("string" => $node->nodeValue);}
```

In the end I need to have an array like this:

```
    Array ( [1] => Array ( [string] => abc [value] => 0,999 ) 
            [2] => Array ( [string] => meh [value] => 0,123 ) 
            [x] => Array ( [string] => xxx [value] => xxx ) )
```

I understand that my code doesn't work, I think I should use array_push, but I was wondering is there are better way to achieve this

Thank you very much

Comment: is the first line (the 'true' case) intended to contain a comma?  I would expect it to contain an assignment.

Comment: Thank you, it shouldn't contain it, it's a spelling error, fixed it.

Comment: Now that I'm at it... are the keys in the second code block intended to be strings?  Then better double-quote them.

Comment: Just to understand the question correctly: do you encounter more than one node per $i, one of which may cause the "string" field to be set, the other the "value" field?

Comment: fixing your code:
if(condition)){$arr[$i]["value"] = $node->nodeValue;}
else{$arr[$i]["string"] = $node->nodeValue;}

Comment: @xtofl the condition is exactly this one ((strpos($node->nodeValue,",").

Each $i has two nodes, one is a string, the other one are numbers with comma in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, the question is not very clear.. Is that what you are trying to do?

```
$result = array();
foreach( $nodes as $node ) 
{
    $type = 'value';
    if( is_string( $node->nodeValue ) )
    {
        $type = 'string';
    }

    $result[][$type] = $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Almost there, with your code I get an array lke this:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => abc ) [1] => Array ( [string] => 0,999 ) [2] => Array ( [value] => meh ) [3] => Array ( [string] => 1,009 ))

while i need to have a value and a string for each array's index:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => abc ) [0] => Array ( [string] => 0,999 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => meh ) [1] => Array ( [string] => 1,009 ))

Comment: Actually adding:
$result[$i][$type] = $node->nodeValue;
Got me everything working as expected.

Thank you

Comment: I believe you need to do it like that: foreach( $nodes as $id => $node ) and then $result[$id][$type] = $node->nodeValue; I am sorry for missing that in the answer - haven't tested it :p

Comment: Tell me, what's the difference with my answer?  Apart from verbosity?

Comment: OK.  I can bear subjective :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it somewhat more concise using the ?: operator:

```
$fieldname = ($condition? "value" : "string"); 
$arr[$i][$fieldname] = $node->nodeValue ;
```